# what does it mean "Make a "U" At the base of the stairs"

Tags: meaning

- Which way's the VIP green room?
- Make a "U" At the base of the stairs and then a left at the hallway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "U" is short for "U-turn", meaning to turn around and go back in the opposite direction.  For example, many countries have signs that tell drivers where it is permissible (or forbidden) to make a U-turn:

[image]

See how this looks like the shape the letter U, turned upside-down.

Where I live we wouldn't say "make a U", so this sounds like either local or personal slang.  We might say

> make a U-ee

or even

> hang a U-ee

There's nothing wrong with "make a U" of course.  Slang is whatever makes sense to those who hear it.

Comment: We say "make a U" or "take a U", along with both options you mention.

Comment: @LorelC.  Or possibly the kind of slang the young kids use these days.  I wouldn't know   :-)